# Injecting/returning a new element on screen

Tags: javascript, mootools

The code below shows that the `div` is injected into the `a` element. How do I display the `div` element so that it is not injected into anything. so instead of

```
<a href="#">
   <div class="example></div>
</a>
```

I have this

```
<a href="#">
</a>
<div class="example></div>
```

JS

```
display: function() {
        var n = new Element('a',{
            'class': 'postItem',
            'data-id': this.id,
            'text': this.title,
            'href': '#',
            events: {
                click: function(){
                    var id = this.get('data-id')
                    callThread(id);
                }
            }
        });

        var deleteT = new Element('div',{
            'class': 'deleteItem',
            'data-id': this.id,
            'text': 'Delete',

            events: {
                click: function(){
                    var deleteID = this.get('data-id')
                    deleteThread(deleteID)
                }
            }

        })

        deleteT.inject(n);
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: did you try jQuery.appendTo(selector) ?

Comment: No, as I am using Mootools not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

mootools `inject` method accept second parameter `[where]`: [Element.inject](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3ainject)

so what you asked is `after`:

```
deleteT.inject(n,'after');
```

Comment: This should work but for some reason nothing! When I try deleteT.inject(n); The text 'Delete' is shown, although when I try what you have suggested the text disappears and nothing is shown.

Comment: well - show your code. as you can see it is working: [http://jsfiddle.net/Karbt/](http://jsfiddle.net/Karbt/)